# Django Form to Model Before Save

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model called Family, and a Django form called FamilyForm.  I save the form in a view as follows:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FamilyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully added the family')
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, 'There was a problem with adding the family')
```

However, my problem is that I would first like to convert this form to a Family object before saving it as I would like to assign some missing properties.

Any idea how to convert the form to a Model object so that I can make the changes before saving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `commit=False` like this

```py
 if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FamilyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save(commit=False)
            # add missing properties
            form.name = ~
            form.age = ~
            # and save it
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully added the family')
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, 'There was a problem with adding the family')
```

Comment: Thanks for the code!  It works, however, only if I assign form.save to a variable and then use that variable to assign and save

Comment: I missed that and I'm glad you solved it. :) @ceds

Answer (score 0):

Saving with commit=False gets you a model object, then you can add your extra data and save it.